# How to get single entity in Entity Framework Core of model with composite key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm pretty new to C# and Entity Framework Core at all. I have a model like:

```
{
    public Guid CompanyCategoryId { get; set; }

    public Guid ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual ParentCategory ParentCategory { get; set; }

    public Guid BaseCategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual BaseCategory BaseCategory { get; set; }

    public Guid CompanyProfileId { get; set; }
    public virtual CompanyProfile CompanyProfile { get; set; }
}
```

The core logic here is I want to prevent situation where one `CompanyProfile` has more than one `BaseCategory`, thus I mark these two as composite key by:

```
builder.Entity<CompanyCategory>()
    .HasKey(c => new { c.CompanyProfileId, c.BaseCategoryId });
```

Now, the question is - is there any way to have another unique value like `CompanyCategoryId` to identify single entity of this model? I need it to get/update single entity on my frontend. Currently value of this field - `CompanyCategoryId` - is Guid but filled with zeros. I guess I can combine these two composite key in DTO and send it as a string to frontend and then again split it to separate keys in the controller. But I think it's rather ugly solutions... I will be really grateful for your help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is simply "how do I make `CompanyCategoryId` required to be unique?" then you should just make and index on that column and mark it unique as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes#index-uniqueness):

```
builder.Entity<CompanyCategory>()
    .HasIndex(b => b.CompanyCategoryId)
    .IsUnique();
```